# Subsetting Dataframe by range of values

Tags: r, subset

I know its a very basic question but I just don't understand why there is a difference in:

```
  extracted_df1 <- df_merged[df_merged$ID >69 & df_merged$ID <73 , ]
  extracted_df2 <- subset(df_merged, ID == 70:72)
```

With the first method I get 6574 observations and with the second method I get just 2190 observations. Why is that?

I would like to use the second method, however it seems that with this method I miss some values?!

Thanks,
niki

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `%in%`, e.g.,

```
subset(df_merged, ID %in% 70:72)
```

to check if values in `ID` fall within the range `70:72`